# Setting DOS Environment Variable to another Environment Variable in if statement

Tags: if-statement, set, dos

This seems so simple, but has turned out to be such a pain.

On Windows 7, I can paste the below into a command prompt and have it set `ProgramFiles(x32)` to either `%programfiles%` or `%programfiles(x86)%`:

```
%comspec% /c if exist "%programfiles%" (set "ProgramFiles(x32)=%programfiles%") else (set %ProgramFiles(x32)=%programfiles(x86)%")
```

However on Windows XP, using the the same and others methods, I cannot get the same result:

```
E:\>%comspec% /c if exist "%programfiles%" (set "ProgramFiles(x32)=%programfiles%") else (set "ProgramFiles(x32)=%programfiles(x86)%")
E:\Program was unexpected at this time.

E:\>%comspec% /c if exist "%programfiles%" (set ProgramFiles(x32)=%programfiles%) else (set ProgramFiles(x32)=%programfiles(x86)%)
E:\Program was unexpected at this time.

E:\>%comspec% /c if exist "%programfiles%" (set "ProgramFiles(x32)"="%programfiles%") else (set "ProgramFiles(x32)=%programfiles(x86)%")
E:\Program was unexpected at this time.

E:\>%comspec% /c if exist "%programfiles%" (set ProgramFiles(x32)="%programfiles%") else (set ProgramFiles(x32)=%programfiles(x86)%)
"E:\Program Files") was unexpected at this time.

E:\>%comspec% /c if exist "%programfiles%" (set ProgramFiles(x32)=%%programfiles%%) else (set ProgramFiles(x32)=%programfiles(x86)%)
%E:\Program was unexpected at this time.
```

set ProgramFiles(x32)=%programfiles% works fine straight from the command line on both Win XP & 7.

What AM I missing?

As a side note, I REALLY wish Microsoft would have made %ProgramFiles% be the directory for 32 bit programs. I can't see the logic in having to do this checking, when it were that way a 32 bit program would be in the same location regardless of the bitage of the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dbenham Very in depth, and very much appreciated enlightenment in another question of mine, solves this one as well - [Different behaviour of DOS Environment setting, in if statement, in DOS prompt as compared to Windows Shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981073/different-behaviour-of-dos-environment-setting-in-if-statement-in-dos-prompt-a/11987337?iemail=1#11987337)

Answer (score 0):

You're really better off programming in almost *anything* but .bat file syntax.  IMHO.

But "what you're missing" is that .bat syntax considers "Program" and "Files" two separate words (instead of *one* part of a path).

Simple workaround:

```
  cd c:\
  dir/x pro*
```

In your case, you'll probably have a "progra~1"  (for "Program files") and "progra~2" (for "program files (x86)".  Just modify your .bat file accordingly :)

Comment: Yes, but "%comspec% /c if exist "%programfiles%" (set "ProgramFiles(x32)=%programfiles%") else (set %ProgramFiles(x32)=%programfiles(x86)%")" works as intended on Win7 & "E:\>%comspec% /c if exist "%programfiles%" (set ProgramFiles(x32)="%programfiles%") else (set ProgramFiles(x32)=%programfiles(x86)%)
"E:\Program Files") was unexpected at this time." is clearly treating it as both words together....

Comment: Also, not sure how your suggestion address the purpose of the command. I need to set a separate variable depending on the bitage of the PC it is running on.